# React Router not displaying anything in vite project

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, vite

I set up a basic react project in vite, but when I tried to add react router to to manage the routing it refused to work and just gives me a blank screen on localhost

**Index html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/Logo.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Project title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Main jsx file**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App'
import './css/index.css'
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom"

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

**App jsx file**

```
// import { useState } from 'react'
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import './css/App.css'
// import { Home } from './pages/Home'


function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<h1>home</h1>}/>
    </Routes>
  )
}

export default App
```

**package json file**

```
{
  "name": "name-of-project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.8",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.2.0",
    "vite": "^3.2.3"
  }
}
```

[image: LIVE SERVER]

[image: FILE STRUCTURE]

I tried putting a single h1 element in the element tag of the route to see if the problem was with the BrowserRouter in the main.jsx as shown above, and I think that that is the case, but I've been going through the documentation and I can't find exactly what is wrong with the code I've written

Comment: I see no overt issue with the code. How are you running the app locally?

Comment: I'm using npm run dev, is there a problem with that?

Comment: Depends on what the `dev` script does I suppose. Can you share your package.json file?

Comment: Sure thing, I just appended it to the original post

Answer (score 0):

The problem was somewhere in the node_modules folder when I installed react router it's self. I'm not exactly sure where, I just re-downloaded everything